# Question on chain rule and composition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I am struggling to apply multi dimensional chain rule to a double composition. In particular how do I calculate :

$$\frac{d}{dt}\big(F\circ f_t \circ g_t \big)$$

where $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$, and $f_t,g_t :\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I don't think you've got this set up properly: you can't differentiate wrt an index.

Comment: @ancientmathematician $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^d$, i.e $(t,x)\mapsto f_t(x)$. not index just weird notation

Comment: Assuming you know how to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}F(h(t))$ it boils down to calculating $\frac{d}{dt}(f_t\circ g_t)$ by another chain rule. Probably easier when you write this as $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t,g(t,x))$ and hold $x$ fixed.

Comment: @KurtG. Is it $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t,g(t,x)))=\partial_t f(t,g(t,x))+Jf(t,g(t,x)) \partial_t g(t)$ where $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$ ?

Comment: Looks right. --

Comment: But it still makes no sense:  you don't mean $f_t\circ g_t$ but $(t,x)\mapsto f(t,g(t,x))$ where $f,g: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{d}\to \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Once you get rid of the mistaken/weird notation it's obvious what the answer is.